# Failed to start lightningd.service: Unit bitcoind.service not found

Tags: lightning-network

I followed the tutorial https://medium.com/@meeDamian/c-lightning-node-on-rbp3-b950660fb835 without error.
When I type:
 sudo systemctl start lightningd 
I get 
 Failed to start lightningd.service: Unit bitcoind.service not found.

Note: Blockchain syncronization is not finished

Any idea?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the top of this tutorial they say: This guide assumes you’re on MacOS, comfortable with terminal, already have a **Bitcoin Full Node** running on Raspberry Pi 3 (optionally with Tor) and now you want to also add a c-lightning node to it.

*bitcoind.service not found* means that you don't have bitcoin-core installed.

Comment: I have launched bitcoind as user "pi" and I can see the progressive blockchain syncronization (not still ended) in debug.log.